# How to update state in redux toolkit store inside and input element in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am working in a react application, It store the user information from the redux store fetched from my back-end api using redux-saga and displaying it to an input element.
What I want is to update the state of input on an 'onChange' event

```
 import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
 const user= useSelector(state => state.user)
 
 const Sample = () => {
    return(
     <>
        <input value={user.firstname} onChange={??} ></input>
        <input value={user.middlename} onChange={??} ></input>
        <button onClick={dispatch(SomeActionToUpdateToBackend())}>Update</button>
     </>
          ) 

 }
```

Should I update the redux state directly or should I put it in a temporary local state and use the dispatch(updateUser({localState})) ?,
I'm new to redux and I'm a little confused.

Comment: Maintain local state or ref and on update, update redux state and api

Comment: I tried dispacthing action on 'onChange', something like < ..., onChange={(e) => dispatch(userOnChange({name:e.target.name,value:e.target.value}))} />
then setup my userOnchange action on my userSlice,(I am using redux-saga) to update the data, It works, but not so sure if its the right way.

Comment: Hey there you need to create an action to update the reducer state which is kept 

in your store so something like if you using toolkit something like reducers: {
updateName(state, action) {
//Depends on how the data is stored
state.user.userName = action.payload
}

then onChange((e) => dispatch(updateName(e.target.value))) which will update the state

If your using plain redux 

pretty much the same thing just a bit extra if you need to know this reply here and I will gladly help if you dont understand

Comment: I have a question, is this a better way? directly manipulating the state in the store on 'onChange' or should I use a local state to store what's with my redux store state and later change the redux state in one go, something like const[sample,setSample] = useState(StateFromReduxStore) ? Im kind of confuse, because everytime I type something, It always dispatch the action. is it not too expensive/heavy to use ?